# Extract some information about WMI query and return this information

Tags: powershell

Im collecting information about WMI query. I save this information in a variable. When i write this variable in console, it shows me the following :

```
@{PasswordState=7}
```

But, when i do an "If" and check if variable contains the number 7, it tell me that is not contained:

```
If($PasswordState -contains "7")
{
    Write-Host Contain 7
}
Else
{
    Write-Host Not contain 7
}
```

Could anyone help me to get the value of WMI Query as `INT`? I mean, i only need the number status of `PasswordState` in class `Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings`.
It seems the WMI is returning an object and my variable is not processing well this returning.
Thank you

```
$PasswordState = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings -namespace root\wmi | Select PasswordState

Write-Host $PasswordState


If($PasswordState -contains "7")
{
Write-Host Contain 7
}
Else
{
Write-Host Not contain 7
}
```

I expect the output `@{PasswordState=7}` to be only 7.

Comment: Change: `$PasswordState = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings -namespace root\wmi | Select PasswordState` To: `$PasswordState = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings -namespace root\wmi | Select -Expand PasswordState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is formatted in a hashed key=value pair, and you want just the value. You can use the -ExpandProperty parameter to assign the value to $PasswordState...

```
$PasswordState = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings -namespace root\wmi | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PasswordState

If ($PasswordState -contains "7") {

    Write-Host "Contain 7"
}

Else {

    Write-Host "Not contain 7"
}
```

You should definitely research and use the evaluation operator that best suits your scenario. -Contains may not be it.

Comment: But then also change the `If ($PasswordState -contains "7")` into `If ($PasswordState -eq 7)`.  `-contains` is wrong here as it is for comparing items in a collection. See [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)